# XSL ¿cómo imprimir valor de cada etiqueta en XML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

tengo un problema con una plantilla `xml`, esta es la plantilla `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="barquetes.xsl" ?>
<BARCOS>
    <DESTINO lugar="Tenerife">
            <PRECIO>
                <IDA edad="niño" tarifa="Canarias">6</IDA>
                <IDA edad="adulto" tarifa="Canarias">12</IDA>

                <IDAYVUELTA edad="niño" tarifa="Canarias">10</IDAYVUELTA>
                <IDAYVUELTA edad="adulto" tarifa="Canarias">20</IDAYVUELTA>

                <IDA edad="niño" tarifa="España">7</IDA>
                <IDA edad="adulto" tarifa="España">14</IDA>
                <IDAYVUELTA edad="niño" tarifa="España">12</IDAYVUELTA>
                <IDAYVUELTA edad="adulto" tarifa="España">24</IDAYVUELTA>

            </PRECIO>
    </DESTINO>
</BARCOS>
```

Esta es la `xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

    <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <HTML>
        <TABLE>
            <xsl:for-each select="BARCOS/DESTINO/PRECIO/IDA">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@tarifa"/>
                <TR>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="@tarifa"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="@edad"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="../IDA"/></TD><!--Línea del error-->
                <BR></BR>
                </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>   
        </TABLE>
    </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Quiero que mostrar el valor de la etiqueta `IDA`donde está comentada la línea del error en el `xsl`, tal como está ahora muestra siempre el valor de la primera etiqueta(6). En este caso, la salida es:

```
Canarias    niño    6
Canarias    adulto  6
España  niño    6
España  adulto  6
```

Si en esa misma línea pongo `/` muestra todas los valores de todas las etiquetas para cada valor, en ese caso, la salida es esta:

```
Canarias    niño    6 12 10 20 7 14 12 24 7 14 12 24
Canarias    adulto  6 12 10 20 7 14 12 24 7 14 12 24
España  niño    6 12 10 20 7 14 12 24 7 14 12 24
España  adulto  6 12 10 20 7 14 12 24 7 14 12 24
```

La salida esperada:

```
 Canarias   niño    6
Canarias    adulto  12
España  niño    7
España  adulto  14
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la versión 1.0 de [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10), la instrucción [`value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#value-of) construye un nodo de texto a partir de aplicarle la función [`string`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-string) a su argumento. Cuando la función `string` recibe como argumento un conjunto de nodos ("[node set](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-sets)") toma el primero de los nodos (en el orden determinado por su aparición en el documento) y devuelve su valor de texto (concatenación de todos los nodos texto descendientes en el caso de un nodo elemento).

El comportamiento observado se explica además porque el contexto para la ejecución de la instrucción [`for-each`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#element-for-each) es por vez cada uno de los nodos seleccionados por la expresión XPath de su atributo `select`; en este caso, todos los elementos que desde el nodo raíz del documento sean seleccionados por la expresión `"BARCOS/DESTINO/PRECIO/IDA"`, es decir, nodos elemento de nombre `IDA`. Cuando nuevamente se quiere "*mostrar el valor de la etiqueta*" pero se lo hace con la instrucción `xsl:value-of select="../IDA"`, en realidad se sigue el camino de seleccionar al padre ("`..`") del contexto (el elemento `IDA` del `for-each`), seguramente el elemento `PRECIO`, y luego se seleccionan **todos** los hijos `IDA` y se opera como ya se describió con la instrucción `value-of`.

Enfatizamos que así se seleccionaran todos los hijos `IDA` de `PRECIO` porque no fue proveído un ejemplo de archivo de entrada y porque en caso que éstos sean varios podría explicarse que el resultado sea siempre el mismo, es decir, el primero de ellos en el orden en que aparecen en el documento.

Suponiendo el siguiente archivo de entrada:

```
<BARCOS>
        <DESTINO>
            <PRECIO>
                <IDA tarifa="Canarias" edad="niño">6</IDA>
                <IDA tarifa="Canarias" edad="adulto">12</IDA>
                <IDA tarifa="España" edad="niño">7</IDA>
                <IDA tarifa="España" edad="adulto">14</IDA>
            </PRECIO>
        </DESTINO>
</BARCOS>
```

Con la siguiente transformación

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <HTML>
        <TABLE>
            <xsl:for-each select="BARCOS/DESTINO/PRECIO/IDA">
            <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@tarifa"/>
                <TR>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="@tarifa"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="@edad"/></TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="."/></TD>
                <!-- Valor de texto de sí mismo, en el contexto de los elementos IDA -->
                <BR></BR>
                </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>   
        </TABLE>
    </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resultará en la siguiente salida

```
<HTML>
   <TABLE>
      <TR>
         <TD>Canarias</TD>
         <TD>niño</TD>
         <TD>6</TD>
         <BR/>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>Canarias</TD>
         <TD>adulto</TD>
         <TD>12</TD>
         <BR/>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>España</TD>
         <TD>niño</TD>
         <TD>7</TD>
         <BR/>
      </TR>
      <TR>
         <TD>España</TD>
         <TD>adulto</TD>
         <TD>14</TD>
         <BR/>
      </TR>
   </TABLE>
</HTML>
```

Con la siguiente visualización

```
Canarias    niño    6
Canarias    adulto  12
España      niño    7
España      adulto  14
```